# Json parsing Python

Tags: python, json

data.json content

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "data_block": [
      {
        "Number": "11097",
        "ID": -61000,
        "Version": "18",
        "Sequence": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "Status": [
          "Booked",
          "Canceled",
          "Canceled"
        ],
        "Name": "abc",
        "EmailAddress": "abc@test.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am looking to get values in below format

Number~Sequence~Status

11097~1|2|3~Booked|Canceled|Canceled

Tried below, but getting

> KeyError: 'data_block'

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

pprint(data)

data["data_block"][0]["Number"]
```

Comment: Because `data_block` is inside `response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data["response"]["data_block"][0]["Number"]
```

Try above line

Comment: data["response"]["data_block"][0]["Number"] worked

Comment: Then your actual value doesn't match what you posted.